# What's the difference between var and let in Zephir

Tags: zephir

I read the Zephir's documentation (https://docs.zephir-lang.com/0.12/en/types) and I'm not sure I understand the difference between `var` and `let` in Zephir. My first thought was that maybe `var` only declares a variable and if you want to assign it to something, you have to use `let`. But then I saw the following lines in the documentation:

```
var a = false, b = true;
var number = 5.0, b = 0.014;
```

and I'm quite confused now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the docs](https://docs.zephir-lang.com/0.11/en/introduction):

> Variables are, by default, immutable. This means that Zephir expects
>   that most variables will stay unchanged. Variables that maintain their
>   initial value can be optimized down by the compiler to static
>   constants. When the variable value needs to be changed, the keyword
>   let must be used.

In other words, your assumption seems right. The reason the sample you posted uses `var` is because those are *initial assignments* as opposed to *reassignments*. Immutable, in that context, means that Zephir expects variables to maintain their original values.

Comment: Yeah, you're right! And the same is true for statically typed variables, so if you want to change the initial value of an integer, for example, you have to put 'let'. It seems only for loop doesn't require that, maybe does it automatically.